# One LOUD bang from underneath front driver side, and then rattling sound over bumps

Tags: rattle

I was driving on smooth stretch of paved road about 20-25 mph and i heard a really loud metallic bang from underneath the front drivers side.  Scared the bejeezus out of me...

And soon after that i now hear a rattling sound going over cracks or bumps.

what happened?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I think this is something you'll have to investigate on your own or by taking it to a shop to have it looked at ... there are just too many variables not mentioned and way too many things which it *might* be for us to be able to tell you.

Comment: I agree there are too many things it *might* be. A similar "bang" once happened to me, driving on a smooth straight road (though more like 60 mph than 20 mph) and the cause was a broken front suspension coil spring. So on the basis of that anecdote, don't ignore it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened is that something on your car broke **or** you picked up a piece of road debris which has gotten caught somewhere. Beyond that it's impossible to say, you have localized the sound, the only way you're going to get to the bottom of it is to look. Be careful and do it right, don't go under the car without it being supported securely. You can also use your mobile phone's camera to take stills or video without getting under the car.